# Using Yahoo OmniAuth in Rails

Tags: oauth, yahoo

I want to make Yahoo OAuth authentication in a Rails Application . I did Google Auth in the similar way but face problem in this case.

**Yahoo app Setup**
[image: "Yahoo app setup"]

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-yahoo_auth'
```

**User.rb**

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :omniauthable, omniauth_providers:[:yahoo_auth]
```

**in initializers/devise.rb**

```
config.omniauth :yahoo_auth,  ENV["YAHOO_APP_ID"] ,ENV["YAHOO_SECRET_ID"],{}
```

**Route**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth'}
  root to: 'home#index'
end
```

**Omniauth Controller**

```
  def yahoo_auth
    raise ""
    if registered_user.present?
      sign_in_and_redirect registered_user
    else
      failure
    end
  end

  def failure
    raise request.params['message'].inspect
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url, error: 'There is a problem signing you in'
  end

  def auth_hash
    request.env['omniauth.auth']
  end

  def registered_user
    email = auth_hash.info.email
    available_user = User.find_by(email: email)
    user = available_user.present? ? available_user : User.create_from_provider_data(auth_hash)
  end
```

**In console I am getting like this.Tt always redirected to failure method, and render a long HTML page:**

```
I, [2020-07-29T19:43:21.483101 #2442]  INFO -- omniauth: (yahoo_auth) Callback phase initiated.
E, [2020-07-29T19:43:22.955112 #2442] ERROR -- omniauth: (yahoo_auth) Authentication failure!
invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, 
{render a long html page I am adding picture
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

}
Processing by OmniauthController#failure as HTML
  Parameters: {"code"=>"pm6t9n9", "state"=>"4e612742be8db7e136e390b2d17743ee194f96e9857289fe"}
```

Comment: it's probably not a good idea to post your keys publicly

Comment: that's the demo one! don't worry :)

Comment: ah ok, that's a relief!